# maximum precision allowable in Cycles Nodes (decimals)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I have noticed that in cycles nodes with numbers, the maximum precision allowable is 1/1000 (0.001). Is there any way to increase it to 1/10,000 (0.0001) or more?

Comment: A lot of times just typing in a value will work if you want to go beyond the limit of the slider on a node. The same works with most other things too. Is it a specific node you're trying to fine tune?

Comment: Color ramp. I am using it to control volume density so that I can get an anvil-shaped cross vertical section for a planetary cloud layer (using a 2D cloud map to determine where the clouds appear). The height of even a very big cloud is still very small compared to the diameter of a planet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply type in the desired value in your color ramp node. The most precise I was able to achieve before Blender made it zero was `0.0000001`.

[image]